# readfile opens in a new page instead of a pop up window to download file

Tags: php, readfile

hi i need help i am using the code below from php.net to allow site visitors download documents on my site

```
<?php

   $file = $_GET['file'];;

   if (file_exists($file)) {
   header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
   header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
   header('Expires: 0');
   header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
   header('Pragma: public');
   header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
   ob_clean();
   flush();
   readfile($file);
   exit;
   }
?>
```

my problem is that instead of the code outputting a dialog box in order for me to save/download the document as outlined here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php the code opens up in a new page showing abnormal data...the code works perfectly on xampp localhost but not on the server

what might be the problem??

Comment: The code seems to be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be perfect. My thoughts is that the configuration of `php.ini` in the server and the xampp might be different.

My suggestion is to run `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in both server and xampp and compare the configuration and match the xampp's configuration in the server.

Comment: which values should i specifically look at?

Comment: First thing, you need to compare the output of both.

Comment: in my server the output_buffering is set to 'no value' while on xampp the value is '4096'...what does this mean?

Comment: I guess `output_bufferring` is something to do with your issue. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773876/problem-with-output-buffering-and-php-ini.